# Android custom listner callback to a different place

Tags: android, interface, callback

I have a general custom listener/callback question. 
In my code, I have the following interface and `LocalDB` class that read room database:

```
# Custom interface
public interface MyInterface {
    void OnSuccess();
    void OnFailure();
}

# Class LocalDB
public class LocalDB {
    private MyInterface myInterface;


    public static PIMUserLocalDataSource getInstance(@NonNull Context context) 
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (PIMUserLocalDataSource.class) {
                INSTANCE = new PIMUserLocalDataSource(context);
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void setCustomListener(CustomListener customListener) {
        this.customListener = customListener;
    }

    private void queryA() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            result = appDatabase.myDao().getQueryA();
            if (result != null) {
                if (customListener != null) {
                    customListener.onSuccess();
                } else {
                    customListener.onFailure();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void queryB() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            result = appDatabase.myDao().getQueryB();
            if (result != null) {
                if (customListener != null) {
                    customListener.onSuccess();
                } else {
                    customListener.onFailure();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Fragment / Activity
LocalDB myDB = LocalDB.getInstance(context)
myDB.setCustomListener(new CustomListener) {
    @Override
    public void OnSuccess() {
        Log.e(logTag, "Success queryA");
    }

    @Override
    public void OnFailure() {
        Log.e(logTag, "Failed queryA");
    }
}
myDB.queryA()

myDB.setCustomListener(new CustomListener) {
    @Override
    public void OnSuccess() {
        Log.e(logTag, "Success queryB");
    }

    @Override
    public void OnFailure() {
        Log.e(logTag, "Failed queryB");
    }
}
myDB.queryB()
```

## Problem

These works fine most of the time, however, there is sometimes that `queryA` is slow and `queryB` is done before `queryA`, `queryB` callback to `queryB` no problem, but when `queryA` is done, it callback to `queryB` listener. I think because the listener of B overwritten A? How should I avoid this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call queryA or queryB. pass the listener.

```
# Custom interface
public interface MyInterface {
    void OnSuccess();
    void OnFailure();
}

# Class LocalDB
public class LocalDB {

boolean successA,successB;


    public static PIMUserLocalDataSource getInstance(@NonNull Context context) 
    {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (PIMUserLocalDataSource.class) {
                INSTANCE = new PIMUserLocalDataSource(context);
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    private void queryA(CustomListener customListener) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            result = appDatabase.myDao().getQueryA();
            if (result != null) {
                if (customListener != null) {
                    customListener.onSuccess();
                } else {
                    customListener.onFailure();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void queryB(CustomListener customListener) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            result = appDatabase.myDao().getQueryB();
            if (result != null) {
                if (customListener != null) {
                    customListener.onSuccess();
                } else {
                    customListener.onFailure();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Fragment / Activity
LocalDB myDB_A = LocalDB.getInstance(context)
myDB.setCustomListener(new CustomListener) {
    @Override
    public void OnSuccess() {
        successA=true;
        checkIfTwoFinishedExcutecode();
        Log.e(logTag, "Success queryA");
    }

    @Override
    public void OnFailure() {
        Log.e(logTag, "Failed queryA");
    }
}
myDB.queryA(myDB_A )

LocalDB myDB_B = LocalDB.getInstance(context)
    @Override
    public void OnSuccess() {
    successB=true;
    checkIfTwoFinishedExcutecode(); 
    Log.e(logTag, "Success queryB");
    }

    @Override
    public void OnFailure() {
        Log.e(logTag, "Failed queryB");
    }
}
myDB.queryB(myDB_B)


void checkIfTwoFinishedExcutecode(){
if(successA&&successB){
// the two is finished. write your code
}


}
```

Comment: i haven't tried the suggestion yet, but LocalDB.getInstance(context) return the same object, so when executing queryB it will reset queryA listener as well, will that be the same problem?

Comment: No it will not.

Comment: Thanks both for your suggestion. I couldn't reproduce with my original code but i went ahead to implement the way you guys suggest and its working fine now. I will report back if the same problem arise again. Consider that it is resolved! Thanks again.